# ASP.NET MVC checkbox and radio button examples

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, radio-button

I am looking for detailed ASP.NET MVC examples which make extensive use of grouped checkboxes (where multiple checkboxes can be selected, use case: choose the magazines you want to subscribe to with options such as "SI", "Forbes", "Money" etc) as well as grouped radio buttons (use case: at a bank choose either "savings" or "checking" account).

I have searched and found only scattered UI snipped but no complete MVC example which makes heavy use of these two UI elements and goes into detail on how the values from these elements are processed in the controller, captured in the model and persisted in the database.

Thanks,

Comment: You will never find GOOD example in MVC of persisting radio button and checkbox values in database. Values of MODELS are persisted in database. Viewmodels and Views are used when drawing ui elements. Model binding is used when model is created for use in controller. Client side html events are deeply separated from everything above.I'd try to search separately for these topics and ask questions on more tight topics on your place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The example here is for HTMLHelper for Checkbox Grouping**

```
 public static class HtmlHelperGroup
{
static string container = @"<div id=""{0}"">{1}</div>";
static string checkboxhtml = @"<input type=""checkbox"" name=""{0}"" value=""{1}"" {3} />{2}</br>";


public static string CheckBoxGroup(this HtmlHelper obj, string name, List<SelectListItem> data)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var content in data)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format(checkboxhtml, name, content.Value,content.Text, content.Selected ? "checked" : string.Empty ));
        }
        return string.Format(container, "container_" + name, sb.ToString());
    }

}


<%=Html.CheckBoxGroup("account", new List<SelectListItem>() 
{
 new SelectListItem() { Text="Checking", Value = "1"  },
new SelectListItem() { Text="Saving", Value = "2"  }}) %>
```

**Hope this helps**